# Text wrap around image two separate angualr components

Tags: css, angular

In angular is it possible to have text wrap around an image if they are in two separate components? Or does the image and text have to live inside the same component? I need this to work if the image is on the left or right

[image]

```
<div class="row">
   <app-img></app-img>
   <app-copy></app-copy>
</div>
```

Comment: Tchbell, you need say to Angular when the img is on the left or in the right. then use [style.float] or [ngStyle] or [ngClass]:https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#built-in-attribute-directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> code simulator: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5wkz8d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Adding style to the component tag solves the problem for me.

```
<div class="row">
  <app-my-img style="float:right"></app-my-img>
  <app-my-copy></app-my-copy>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="row">
  <app-my-img style="float:left"></app-my-img>
  <app-my-copy></app-my-copy>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to only work if the image is on the left

Comment: @Tchbell, change the float to `right` it works for me